# How to filter data after using get contents

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I want to know how to find a number on a remote website and make it a variable.

For example, if I want to find the stock quote for "AMZN", I would use curl or get contents on the page "http://stock-quotes.com/AMZN" to make it a variable string called $contents

Now that I have $contents, how would I find that AMZN quote?  I was thinking of using a regular expression to narrow down the line, like finding "AMZN=35 points", and then perform another function to delete the "AMZN=" and " points" at the start and end of the string so that "35" is all that's left.

Is that how people do it?

Comment: the best way is with DOM, but matching using preg_match('#AMZN=(.*) points#',$contents,$match) is easy but if the markup changes the match would break, would need to see the actual page tho

Comment: Why not post this as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @AJ as using reg expression match instead of DOM usually ends with downvotes

Comment: It gets downvotes because it's very fragile.  That said, so is SimpleXMl et al; they generally don't handle badly formed HTML at all.  If you run it through HTMLPurifier first, then try SimpleXML you may have better luck.

http://htmlpurifier.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've always done (say in spidering, etc.) is to use the simple_html_dom library in PHP, then inspect the markup for the site.

The downside, as mentioned before, is that if the markup changes, you'll need to modify your code, but usually it's fairly easy, and if you use a source that has informative markup (consistent class names on the elements you need, etc.), then it's even easier.

Library link: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

1.) DOM Element

2.) Simple XML

3.) preg_match

4.) strpos

Comment: Are these steps or 4 different methods I could use?

Comment: They are 4 different methods that you could use. they are listed as per goodness